# GA Checkout Behavior - data difference between two properties

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, enhanced-ecommerce

I have setup two different properties namely V1 and V2 for GA for same ecommerce website. The ecommerce is built in AngularJS 1.5.11 and it is been running different events in different properties. Over time due to data being scattered in different properties V1 and V2, we have created new property V3 to migrate all the events in 1 place. I have done all the events migration in new property V3 last month.

Over last month, I have checked the ecommerce data and compare against V2 and V3 properties for checkout behaviour and I see different data for same steps.
E.g step 1 is showing 9522 sessions for V2 and 9200 sessions for V3
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySTm9.png)
V3 data for Checkout Behaviour

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t62i4.png)
V2 data for Checkout Behaviour

Is there anyway I can find why there are more sessions in V2 than V3?

Comment: Are the filters applied to the two views the same?

Comment: @MichelePisani yes views settings are exactly same